# Facing issue calling user control code behind method from Js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to call Usercontrol code behind method from the Javascript file which is in a shared location.

Js file code present in shared location

```
function ValidateParams(fromdate,Id)
{
 var exp=/^((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\/]((0?[1-9]|[0-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\/]((0?[1-9]|[0-2][0-9])|(30)))|(0?[2][\/](0?[1-9]|[0-2][0-9])))[\/]\d{4}$/;
 var exp1=/^(\d{9})$/;
 if(exp.test(fromdate)&& exp1.test(Id)) 
 {
   CheckValidityofId("FormUI.CheckValidity",fromdate,Id)
 }
}

function CheckValidityofId(lookupFunction,fromdate,Id) {

    callback = function(response) {
    
        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
        }
        else {
        
            else if (response.value =="NotAssociated")
            {
            document.getElementById(MessageID).innerText="Number is not associated";
            }
            else
            {
            document.getElementById(MessageID).innerText="This is NOT eligible";
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    if (fromdate.length > 0 && Id.length >0) {
        eval(lookupFunction + "('" + fromdate + "','" + Id + ")");
    }
    return false;
}
```

FormUi is usercontrol page with codebehind like this

```
 public partial class FormUI : UIView
    {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(FormUI));
       }
       [Ajax.AjaxMethod()]
        public string CheckValidity(string FromDate, string Id)
        {
          // logic goes here
        }
    }
```

I checked in console,it showing error as

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FormUI is not defined
    at eval (eval at CheckValidityofId(_Default.js:275:3), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at CheckValidityofId(_Default.js:275:3)
    at ValidateParams(_Default.js:239:10)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (?pn=Controls%2fFormUI%2fFormUI&DLN=231307019282:665:406)
```

Please let me know how to refer the usercontrol method in javscript method in a shared location file.